# Is there a windows application which does EXACTLY what the network tab does Chrome dev tools?

Tags: windows, debugging, operating-system, command-prompt

In the network tab in Chrome dev tools, if I click on a button on a website, I can see any ajax calls made to different servers and what data was sent and received.

Does such a tool exist for windows desktop programs? So basically I'm looking for something that sits in between a windows program and the internet so I can see what calls the program makes and what data is received back.

Any ideas?

Comment: For HTTP(S) there is Fiddler, more generally you would need to work at the level of the raw packets (eg. Wire Shark).

Answer (score 0):

I tried wire shark but couldn't get it to give me what I needed.
Microsoft Network Monitor did the job nicely!